# How to modify method utilize an Enum member

Tags: java, date

I wrote a method that calculates all the date & times someone should take the medication by parsing in the medication start and end dates. I need help modifying the method to support PRN medications (take as needed method) within the date range ( start to stop). 
Secondly, if a medication has no end date, without overloading the method (not parsing an end date), how can I make the same method handle a situation where medication has no end date?

I wrote an enum in a different class that holds all the possible time of the day (not dates) when a medication can be taken.

```
public enum timeOfDay {
    morning,
    afternoon,
    evening,
    night,
    every_four_hours,
    with_meal,
    before_bed,
    PRN_as_needed
}


    public void datesAndTimeToTakeMedication (Date medicationStartDate, Date medicationEndDate) {
        List<Date> datesToTakeMedication = new ArrayList<Date>();
        final long milliSecToHour = 1000 * 24 * 60 * 60;
        long start = medicationStartDate.getTime();
        long end = medicationEndDate.getTime();
        while (medicationStartDate.after(medicationEndDate) ||
            medicationStartDate.equals(medicationEndDate)) {
            datesToTakeMedication.add(new Date(start));
            start += milliSecToHour;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < datesToTakeMedication.size(); i++) {

            Date myDate = (Date) datesToTakeMedication.get(i);
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");
            String s = sdf.format(myDate);
            TimeZone mytimezone = TimeZone.getDefault();
            long timeOffset = mytimezone.getOffset(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET);
            System.out.println(s + "is between start and stop dates, 
                with offset of"    +  timeOffset);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It sounds like a different use case, e.g., the existing method is not usable for PRN medications.  A new method should probably be created.  Perhaps the existing method should be refactored to return an `Instructions` object, with the existing method setting a `List<Date>` within an `Instructions` instance.  A new method could set some other appropriate attribute of an `Insructions` instance.  Also, consider using `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime`, or `ZonedDateTime` instead of `Date`.

Comment: A possible hack for medication without end date is to set an artificial end date 200 years into the future since no one is expected to live that long. I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate` and other classes from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Also format pattern strings are case sensitive, don’t confuse `MM` with `mm`.

Comment: **Please consult with the business for requirements on the PRN use case.**  Even though they are often simplified as "take as needed", these types of medication have the flip side of your story... when should they not be took (e.g. frequency, before/after, with/without, etc.) and when they expire or no longer after dates.